# Mapping Facebook "cover" attribute to Cognito User Pool "Picture" attribute not working

Tags: amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-facebook, aws-userpools

I have mapped Facebook "cover" attribute to Cognito User Pool "Picture" attribute and it used to work. But now I'm getting 404 in the response of the Picture mapped to Cognito User Pool.

Answer (score 2):

You need to map picture -> picture. ( Create a custom attribute for facebook provider )

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/

Then you can get the url in picture.data.url